# Execute a psql command from batch without having a separate window popup for the password?

Tags: postgresql, passwords

If I execute a psql command in a hidden cmd process it will open up a cmd asking for the password (I'm doing this from C# by starting a new CMD.exe process with the respective args). Is there a way to avoid this? Ideally the password won't be stored anywhere, it will simply be passed as an arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL will automatically look for a an environment variable called PGPASSWORD before it requests one.  If the environment variable is set it will continue on without asking for a password.

You can set the environment variable before hand in a batch script and then set it to nothing when done.  Like so:

```
set PGPASSWORD=%1
pgsql.exe your arguments here
set PGPASSWORD=
```

Assuming you're passing the password as the first argument to the batch script this will set PGPASSWORD to what ever you pass it.